# Understanding Gauss's law for magnetism using classical concepts

Tags: magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations, gauss-law

How to show with the help of diagrams that magnetic lines of force, whatever their origin, have no divergence?

Comment: It might help to show what type of field line diagram you want to use.

Comment: Case 1. Field lines of a bar magnet; Case 2. Field lines due to an electric current in an wire passing through a closed surface Case 3. Field lines due a loop of wire enclosed by a closed surface ... any other cases

Comment: Is it not sufficient to show that the field lines form closed loops and do not *diverge* from any location (i.e. there are no magnetic monopoles for field lines to start or stop on)?

Comment: But that's how we prove there are no magnetic monopoles

Comment: No magnetic monopoles and no divergence of the field are essentially the same thing. If you have "proven" no magnetic monopoles, then you have no divergence of the field as well.

Comment: Yes. This is convincing. When I studied magnetism for the first time 50 years ago I had 'understood' that there are no magnetic monopoles. Now my mind is looking for a proof...Is there any?

Comment: You can prove it from the Biot-Savart law, but this is based on experiment. At the end of the day there isn't a proof that the universe must be this way. It just is.

Comment: Duplicate/related? [What is the physical meaning of divergence?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451670/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-divergence) and the links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divergence actually means how much a field line spreads. The electric field normally spreads all around hence positive divergence.

However the magnetic field line actually encloses in a closed loop path. So, if you take a particular region then the magnetic field going inward and outward would be the same(and that's what Gauss's  law for magnetism says actually).

Meaning the net divergence and net convergence is equal which results zero divergence in other language net zero spreading around.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add up.
Divergence means how much spread has occured in the field or in your case field lines. When you see that field lines are only emerging and spreading out, then you have a divergence. Electric charges follow this rule if they are isolated as you will see all lines coming out from the positive charge and until and unless there is a begative charge nearby, you will always see the lines spreading out from positive charge and not sinking anywhere.

Now comes what you asked, the case for magnetic field lines.
You see there is another term convergence, which in other meaning means sinking/coming into or say meeting back. This can be seen for field lines coming into negative electric charge.
So to show the magnetic field lines having zero divergence, you have to show that of you take a field line starting from a point and you take it point A, then you use the fact that the magnetic monopoles dont exist and there will be another point B. And meet all the lines here. So by this fact and diagram you show that the lines have a start so a divergence but they also sink at a point also so here the lines comverge. Hence there are no such lines that keep spreading and spreading out form a source.

Also as suggested in the comments, we know that magentic field exists in loop around the current carrying wire.  Here also for the magnetic field you cannot determine a starting/originating pint and  ending/sinking point of the field lines. So we see they do not keep spreading out and have zero divergence. 
And another 3rd diagram you can make is keep a magnet in a closed surface and make field lines coming out of the surface from the north pole and entering back into that surface only by the south pole. See there is no way that the lines have an exact source and keep spreading as the source is where they come back
Hence the Gauss law says:
The amount of magentic flux around a closed surface is always zero.

Hope you have understood it : )

Answer (score 0):

The Gauss law states that the net magnetic field lines through any closed surface are zero. This means that number of field lines entering a surface is equal to the number of field lines leaving it. Unlike charges you don't have an isolated magnetic pole and they always exist in pairs. Thus for magnetic fields, you don't have a source and sink and thus for any closed surface the net magnetic flux through it will be zero.